# Polyhedron with parallel sides that are different n-gons

Tags: polyhedra

Imagine a polyhedron of 7 triangles and 7 quadrilaterals, where each quadrilateral is parallel to one of the triangles.  Is a relaxed version of that possible -- any number of sides is allowable, where each side is parallel to a polygon with a different number of sides.

If that's possible or easy, can the faces have roughly the same area?  Can an inner sphere be tangent to all faces?

Comment: There is no such polyhedron even without the parallelness condition.
It would have  $\frac{3\cdot 7+4\cdot 7}2$ edges.

Comment: If faces can be paired into parallels and are tangent to a sphere, then reflaction at the center permutes the touching points, which is all we need to reconstruct the polyhedron. Consequently, oppisng faces are congruent.

Comment: A **truncated tetrahedron** is an example of such polyhedron (in a relaxed version, that is): each triangle is parallel to certain hexagon. However, the faces are of different area, and the inner sphere doesn't touch them all, and if you try do match _any_ of these requirements, you achieve that at a cost: in effect, your polyhedron ceases to be what it used to be, and becomes an **octahedron**.